# How can I find out who has blocked me on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I don't know who has blocked me on Facebook and wish to know.  Is there a page where I can see the people who have blocked me.

Comment: That would kind of defeat the purpose of a "block", no?

Answer (score 9):

**You cannot find it out**

You cannot see who has blocked you on Facebook. If the user who has blocked you has checked the "report this to user" button, then you will be informed that you have been blocked for so and so reason, but the username of the user who has blocked you will not be revealed. This is part of Facebook's privacy and security measures. And to block a user from Facebook at least more than 3 users should report against you.

Note: Have a look at this question too [How can I know if one of my friends on Facebook is blocking me?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-can-i-know-if-one-of-my-friends-on-facebook-is-blocking-me?rq=1)

Comment: Go through fb privacy policy over here    https://www.facebook.com/privacy/explanation